# toggle- hide item when click outside of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery's slidetoggle, want to learn how to make the `showup` class hide when click anywhere outside of the DIV.
thanks!

Online SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/

```
<div class="click">click me</div>
<div class="showup">something I want to show</div>​
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click').click(function(){
        $(".showup").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});​
```

```
.showup {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px; 
    background: red; 
    display:none;
}
.click {
    cursor: pointer;
}
    ​
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Stop event propagation from within the `.showup` area:

```
$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".showup").hide();
});
```

Then prevent those clicks on `.showup` from bubbling up to the `document`:

```
$(".showup").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any click event that reaches the `document` will result in the `.showup` element being hidden. Any click events that start from within `.showup` will be prevented from proceeding any further up the DOM tree, and thus will never reach the `document`.

You will also need to stop any clicks on your button from traveling up to the `document` as well:

```
$(".click").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".showup").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Otherwise that click event will bubble up to the `document` and result in the hiding of `.showup` immediately.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/2/

Comment: Working Fine :) Thanks for this :)

Comment: If there is form inside the `.showup` part, that form will be never executed

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to record clicks on `.showup` panel (lets say you want it to be more then a simple informative panel), calling `event.stopPropagation()` on clicking it will make that panel untouchable/useless. Use `event.cancelBubble = true` instead and will let the event occur on `.showup` childs.

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    $(".showup").toggle();
});

$(".showup").on("click", function (/*nothing here*/) {
    event.cancelBubble = true
});

$(document).on("click", function () {
    $(".showup").hide();
});
```