# Toggle Div using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div which i want to toggle on click of a button. Its working but the div is not hiding on click of outside button. Below is my code pls check.

```
                <div class='settings' ng-click="showDiv = !showDiv"></div>
                <div class="profileSetting text-center" ng-show="showDiv">
                    <div></div>
                    <p class="small-font">Stephen Wilson <br/> steave@gmail.com</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="small-font"><img src = "images/settings.png" alt = "Generic placeholder thumbnail"> settings</p>

                </div>
```

I want this profilesetting div should be hidden on click of outside.

Comment: what do you mean "on click of outside"?  clicking anywhere on the page?

Comment: Refer this link it may be helpful to you :[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831064/toggle-hide-item-when-click-outside-of-the-div)

Comment: yes any where on the page @plong0